# Suppose $f$ is a one-one function from $X$ to $Y$ and $f^{-1}(U)\subset f^{-1}(V)$, where $U$,and $V$ be the subsets of $Y$,then$U\subset V$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can someone prove this. In general it is not true i.e. If $f^{-1}(U)\subset f^{-1}(V)$, then it is not always true that $U\subset V$ in $Y$.

Comment: How about $U=\emptyset,V=Y$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Take $X$ and $Y$ to be the positive integers and $f(n)=2n$. Then consider $U=\{1,2\}$ and $V=\{2,4\}$. We have $f^{-1}(U)=\{1\}\subset f^{-1}(V)=\{1,2\}$. In other words for $U\subseteq V$ we need $f$ to be surjective as well as injective.

Comment: If $U$ contains elements not in the image of $f$, then it is not necessarily true that $U\subset V$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my suggested answer, written in haste, so read it critically:

$f$ is a bijection $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$, so $g :=f^{-1}$ is a well defined bijection $g \colon Y \rightarrow X$, with $g(f^{-1}(U)) = U$ and $g(f^{-1}(V)) = V$. $f^{-1}(U) \subset f^{-1}(V)$ means that $\forall \ x \in f^{-1}(U) \colon \ x \in f^{-1}(V)$, and $\forall \ y \in U \exists \ x \in f^{-1}(U) \colon y = g(x)$. From this one can conclude that $\forall y \in U: y \in V$, ie. $U \subset V$